# Querying reading Binary data from MYSQL Database Table

Tags: mysql

I have migrated data from Oracle to MYSQl in AWS RDS DB.
One of the DB table has a column having data in binary BLOB format.
How can I query and read Binary data?

Comment: The only way to 'read' data in sql is to select it - so I am unclear what your question is.